# changing the colour of an object based on variable value

Tags: javascript

I need to change the colour of an object (a rectangle used as a paddle) for one second every 10 seconds (eg, turn a white rectangle red for 1 sec).

In my code the colour of the object is set to white as default here:

```
 canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
  canvasContext.fillRect(paddleWidth,paddleOneY,paddleWidth,paddleHeight); // x, y, w, h
```

but I am unsure how/where to set the colour to change periodically. Should I update the code at fillStyle to a function that changes the colour or can I set it to change separately and leave the default fillStyle as white?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not real clear, but maybe something like this?

```
var colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue'];
var idx = 0;

setInterval(function(){ 
  canvasContext.fillStyle = colors[idx++ % 3];
  canvasContext.fillRect(paddleWidth,paddleOneY,paddleWidth,paddleHeight);
}, 1000);
```

that code will change the color every second.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

function changeColor()
{
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
    setTimeout(revert,1000)
   
}

function revert()
{
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
}

setInterval(changeColor,10000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure this is what you need but here you go.
To be honest I think for your case is better to use SVG, because then you do not need to redraw the shape.